# Hyperledger Fabric maximum number of peers

Tags: performance, nodes, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, scalability

I am looking for the scalability limits of Hyperledger Fabric v 1.2 in terms of maximum number of peer nodes. I found some test results that claim maximum 26 for Fabric 1.0. I understand that more nodes will not increase number of concurrent transactions proportionally but that's not a concern for my use case, I just need more peers on the network.